# (Kotlin - Set ImageView with online URL svg image) D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'

Tags: android, kotlin, inputstream, decode, bitmapfactory

I'm making a little geography app where I wish to display a country's flag (svg).
The flag image resources are online link (in svg format).

Eg: Albania Flag - > **https://flagcdn.com/al.svg**

This is my code:

```
flag = "https://flagcdn.com/al.svg"

val thread = Thread {
        try {

            val flagURL = URL(flag)

            println("variable URL : ${flagURL }")

            val flagValue = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(flagURL.openConnection().getInputStream())

            println("variable in flagValue : ${flagValue}")

            binding.flagValue.setImageBitmap(flagValue)

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            println("failed")
        }
    }
    thread.start()
```

When the code runs, an error is detected in the try / catch section:

**D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'**

**I/System.out: variable in flagValue : null**

---

I got my code from this [previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android), but it doesn't work for me. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Coil dependency works, Add below dependencies in gradle,

```
 implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:1.2.0")
 implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-svg:1.2.0")
```

And use below code,

```
fun ImageView.loadImageFromUrl(imageUrl: String) {
    val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(this.context)
        .componentRegistry { add(SvgDecoder(this@Splashh))
        }
        .build()

    val imageRequest = ImageRequest.Builder(this.context)
        .crossfade(true)
        .crossfade(300)
        .data(imageUrl)
        .target(
            onSuccess = { result ->
                val bitmap = (result as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
                this.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
            },
         
        )
        .build()

    imageLoader.enqueue(imageRequest)
}
```

Call method,

```
    var flag = "https://flagcdn.com/al.svg"
    img.loadImageFromUrl(flag)
```

[image]